# the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfil the request/ the resource is not ready

Tags: google-compute-engine

the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfil the request/ the resource is not ready

I failed to start my instance (through the web browser), it gave me the error:

**"The zone 'projects/XXXXX/zones/europe-west2-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."**

I thought it might be the quota problem at first, after checking my quota, it showed all good. Actually, I listed the available zones, europe-west2-c was available, but I still gave a shot to move the zone. Then I tried  "gcloud compute instances move XXXX --zone europe-west2-c --destination-zone europe-west2-c", however, it still failed, popped up the error:

**"ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Instance cannot be moved while in state: TERMINATED"**

Okay, terminated... then I tried to restart it by "gcloud compute instances reset XXX", the error showed in the way:

**ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.reset) Could not fetch resource: - The resource 'projects/XXXXX/zones/europe-west2-c/instances/XXX' is not ready**

I searched the error, some people solved this problem by deleting the disk. While I don't want to wipe the memory, how could I solve this problem?

BTW, I only have one instance, with one persistent disk attached.

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to deploy and balance your workload across multiple zones or regions[1](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps) to reduce the likelihood of an outage, by building resilient and scalable architectures.

If you want an immediate solution, create a snapshot [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots), then create an instance from the snapshot with different zone or region [3](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot).

After migrating it you are still experiencing the same issue, I suggest to contact GCP support[4](https://cloud.google.com/contact/).

---